# Web Application Publishing on Citrix with Restricted Access

Tags: security, web-applications, citrix

We have a Citrix setup enabling users to access our applications from home. Basically, they login to our site using the Windows Authentication. Once, the are successfully logged in, they see the following icons 
Desktop - Full Screen (which provides them the Desktop as they would see when the login in our office)

We now have a requirement where we would like to publish a web application, hxxp://ourlibrary on Citrix with the following security requirement. 
(this application is already accessible if the users launch the desktop and launch IE within it and navigate to it)
The requirement is this -

1. When the are successfully authenticated to our site, they should be able to see The Internet Explorer icon only, NOT the Dekstop - Full Screen icon.
2. On clicking on the icon, Internet Explorer should open up and should automatically navigate to hxxp://ourlibrary
3. They should not be able to access any other URL, such as Google, Hotmail etc.,
4. They should not be able to go File>Open> and Browse
5. They should not be able to do File>Save> and Browse

In effect, they should be able to view the site and that should be it. Any ideas on how to accomplish the security feature? We have already published the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have user to use only on web site for eg; www.mywebsite.com then publish as

iexplore.exe -k www.mywebsite.com